`--pattern=regex` option in less behave unexpectedly
I have a file a.txt,

one two
two one

my goal is to match the 'one' that is at the end of the sentence.
if it is opened in less (less a.txt) , and manually searched by regex  (/one$),
as expected, it will match the 'one' in second line.
However if it is opened with,
less --pattern='one$' a.txt,
opened file will match the both 'one's.
I also tried less '+/one$' a.txt, which resulted in same outcome.

This behavior appears to be due to $ acting as a terminator/separator in the LESS environment variable, leaking into option parsing:

Some  options  like -k or -D require a string to follow the option letter.  The string for that option is considered to end when a dollar sign ($) is found.  For example, you can set two -D options like this:
 LESS="Dn9.1$Ds4.1"


You can tell by the way you can specify one option inside another using $. The following ignores the one because it gets overwritten by a -ptwo:
less --pattern='one$ptwo' a.txt

